# grunt-contrib-compress fails when using 'tar'

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compress

I'm trying to make this compressor to output **tgz** files using this configuration. This works perfectly fine with ".zip" instead of ".tar.gz" as the file extension and with "zip" as mode. Howevever I can't make it work with the tar/tgz format.

```
module.exports = function (paramsConfig) {
'use strict';

return {
    'main': {
        'options': {
            'archive': 'filePath/fileName.tar.gz',
            'mode': 'tar',
            'level': 9
        },
        'files': [
            {
                'cwd': 'distributionDir/../',
                'expand': true,
                'src': ['**/*']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

};

Whenever I try to run the compressor with the tar configuration, this is the error printed:

> `Fatal error: The "string" argument must be of type string. Received type number`

This is strange because it does compress all the files albeit ending with that error.